# MPD get rid of?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Can people defeat Multiple Personality Disorder? After seeing Mike get rid of all his personalities by "the push of a button" and defeating Mal I've always wondered if people can defeat it...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociative_identity_disorder#Treatment